# Additional mail check by a custom script on Exchange Server

Tags: email, exchange, imap

Customer would like to check e-mail content (including attachment parsing) from a list of accounts and, in case of some detected trigger words, to send a copy of the mail to a person who has to be aware.

A fast head-on solution was to send copies of all received mails to an in-between address, which is monitored by the parsing script developed in Python. However it is an additional load for the Exchange mail server deployed at the customer side.

Is there a smarter way, e.g., on the level of hub transport servers, to have the mail check with a custom self-developed script/program for a defined list of corporate accounts (addresses only in the list, without access credentials)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really need to run some custom logic applied to a mail flow, you can go with **Exchange Transport Agents**. With them you can get your custom code invoked during specific stages of the SMTP sessions or message processing. This feature is available in on-premises Exchange only.

See Microsoft docs for more details:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/mail-flow/transport-agents/transport-agents?view=exchserver-2019